# printing session arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, session, printing

I am trying to integrate a booking script to wordpress.

this is the search.php in this file input values are posted to  details.php

```
Line 76:        $_SESSION['svars_details'] = array();
Line 188:       if($tmpctr > 1) array_push($_SESSION['svars_details'], $searchresult);
```

and this is the details.php

```
 $this->setMyParamValue($this->searchVars, 'SESSION', 'svars_details', NULL, true);
```

somehow it takes input / selectbox values as array but I think some of sessions doesn't send through wordpress post.
how can I print this "svars_details session values" as array to see the problem.
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Are you just looking for `var_dump`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a debugger like [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) to set breakpoints in your code and check the value of the variable, wherever you need to know its value.

An other option would be using [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) or [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r) to print the value of the variable to your screen or a log file.

Comment: I installed xdebug but I couldn't use it. how can i set breakpoints in my code?

Comment: You can easily use it with an IDE like PHPStorm or Netbeans, but I think it's possible using a terminal as well. The other option is easier to set up though, while Xdebug gives you more options.

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem using var_dump. Later I will try to install PHPstorm to use xdebug.